# Crazy Coincidence with Mersenne Twister

Tags: php, mersenne-twister

I am a college student from Nanjing University of Posts and Telecommunications and I am currently a member of NJUPT ICPC Team. We are at summer training section and I wrote a program to pick a random student to give their solution to some problems and I am using Mersenne Twister to achieve that and something really really strange happened.

Here is what happened: Each day at 12 o'clock we start the program, pick a random student, and then after he finished we move on to pick another, the whole process would be completed in 10 or 20 minutes and we would pick 4 students at a time. But one student, let's call him A, was pick up every time. ICPC Team has a number of 70 members, and we now picked 6 times, and A was picked 6 times among all 24 picked students.

I had run a diagnosis program after 4th time, and the possibilities seem to follow the equal distribution.

The Code is written in PHP, I am using PHP 7.3.4 with `array_rand()`.

list.txt contains all members separated by commas.

```php
<?php
    $list=explode(",",file_get_contents("list.txt"));
    $index=array_rand($list);
    $target=$list[$index];
    echo $target;
?>
```

Every day, we pick the guy up and he is almost crazy. He complained that to me a few times.